# Is it possible to get value stored in session to Client App built using worklight?

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have stored value in session from **worklight** adapter by writing following piece of code :

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
var session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("dataToExport", "Data To Return");
```

Is it possible to retrieve this value from **client app** using some `worklight api` or other way?

Comment: FYI : I am using worklight 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WL.Server.getClientReuest`, perhaps you can use `WL.Client.addGlobalHeader` in your client-side code.

[WL.Client.addGlobalHeader](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-7&lang=en)

> **AddGlobalHeader(headerName, headerValue)**
>   Adds an HTTP header to be used in server requests issued by
>   an IBM Worklight framework. The HTTP header is used in all requests
>   until removed by the WL.Client.removeGlobalHeader API call.

`WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("MyCustomHeader","abcdefgh");`

Comment: But my requirement is to store data in session, and data is too long. approximately 10 MB.

Comment: Please expand on the scenario. You can store session data on the server. You say that your data is "too long", about 10Mb. What are you expecting to happen to the 10Mb of data? For it to be transmitted to the client on every request? Or is it enough to access portions of it, perhaps in a dedicated call? Focus on when you expect the data to be transferred to the client, irrespective of particular Worklight APIs.